# Power Set Axiom. Terence Tao' analysis 3.4.6

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Currently, I am studying through Terence Tao's Analysis. I encountered the difficulty with proving one of the exercises. Could you please write the proof for the following lemma ?

> **Lemma**: Let $X$ be a set. Then the set $\{ Y : Y \subset X\}$ is a
>   set.

Tao provides the hint and says that proof is related to the following axiom

> **Power set axiom.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Then there exists a set,
>   denoted $Y^X$ , which consists of all the functions from $X$ to $Y$ , thus $f \in Y^X \Leftrightarrow (f \text{ is a function with domain } X \text{ and range } Y )$.
>
> **Replacement axiom.** Let $A$ be a set. For any object $x \in A$, and any object $y$, suppose we have a statement $P(x, y)$ pertaining to $x$ and
>   $y$, such that for each $x \in A$ there is at most one $y$ for which $P(x, y)$
>   is true. Then there exists a set $\{y : P(x, y) \text{ is true for some } x \in A\}$,
>   such that for any object $z$, $z \in \{y : P(x, y) \text{ is true for some } x \in A\} \Leftrightarrow
>  P(x, z) \text{ is true for some } x \in A$.
>
> **Hint**. Start with the set ${(0, 1)}^X$ and apply the replacement axiom,
>   replacing each function $f$ with the object $f^{−1}(\{1\})$.)

Comment: Probably the hint wants you to start with set $\{0,1\}^X$ (not $(0,1)^X$).

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=\{0,1\}^X$ and let $P(f,Y)$ be the statement:$$Y=\{z\mid (z,1)\in f\}$$ or equivalently:$$\forall z[z\in Y\iff\exists p[p\in f\wedge p=(z,1)]$$The expression $p=(z,1)$ can be written in a more elementary way, if you like.

Then for every $f$ there is exactly one $Y$ for which $P(f,Y)$ is true.

So according to the replacement axiom a set: $$\{Y\mid P(f,Y)\text{ is true for some }f\in A\}$$ exists.

So if we can show that this set *only* contains subsets of $X$ and secondly contains *every* subset of $X$ then we have proved that the collection $$\{Y\mid Y\text{ is a subset of }X\}$$ coincides with the set, hence *is* a set.

The first thing is evident because every $f\in A$ is a set of ordered pairs that have an element of $X$ as first coördinate.

For the second thing: if $Y$ is a subset of $X$ then there is a function $f_Y\in A$ prescribed by $z\mapsto 1$ if $z\in Y$ and $z\mapsto 0$ otherwise. Then evidently $\{z\mid (z,1)\in f_Y\}$ coincides with $Y$.

Comment: I have one question about your answer. In the last part of your proof, I don't understand how the last part indicates that $\{Y| P(f,Y) \text{is true for some} f \in A\}$ contains every subset of $X$. Could you elaborate this a little bit?

Comment: @shk910 For proving that $\{Y\mid P(f,Y)\text{ is true for some }f\in A\}$ indeed contains every subset of $X$ it is enough to pick out some subset $Y_0$ of $X$ and then to prove that this set is an element of $\{Y\mid P(f,Y)\text{ is true for some }f\in A\}$. So it is enough to find a function $f_0\in A$ such that $P(f_0,Y_0)$ is true. If we take for $f_0$ the function that is prescribed by $z\mapsto1$ if $z\in Y_0$ and $z\mapsto0$ otherwise then we have reached that goal. This because in that case $Y_0=\{(z,1)\mid (z,1)\in f_0\}$ (do you understand why?) or shortly "$P(f_0,Y_0)$ is true".

Comment: Oh, I see. I have one more thing. Why is the element of $Y_0$  2-tuple? do you mean $\{z | (z, 1) \in f_0\}$ ?

Comment: @shk910 Oh, yes. That's wrong and also the answer is infected with it. I will repair. Thank you for attending me.

Comment: What is the significance of {${0,1}$}$^X$? Must the range only contain two elements (and specifically $0$ and $1$), or are they arbitrary?

Comment: @299792458 It is sufficient and necessary that we are dealing with two distinct elements. So not specifically 0 and 1.

Comment: I have asked about this exercise too, as this specific answer is too advanced for me, I need to proceed in smaller steps. I would welcome comments/advice there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879930/unsure-of-logic-in-my-proof-that-power-set-axiom-for-functions-implies-existence