# meaning of "$\wedge$" in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been reading Analysis I by Terence Tao and this symbol, $\wedge$, keeps popping in proof's in this forum as well as from other sources, for example, [Power Set Axiom. Terence Tao' analysis 3.4.6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538905/power-set-axiom-terence-tao-analysis-3-4-6). This symbol is not described in the book so I do not understand what this means, could anyone explain it please? Thank you.

Comment: If you mean $\wedge$, here it just means "and".

Comment: @OttavioBartenor Okay but why not write an answer

Comment: @OttavioBartenor Thank you for the help.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov It didn't felt right to write it as an answer, it was just half a line.

Comment: "Power set" indicates it's not "and". But the linked question explains the notation fully. Maybe OP can explain where they are stuck.

Comment: @OttavioBartenor: I agree, but that usage does not match what is happening in the link; there it is just the exponentiation.

Comment: @KristianStokkereit: Do you mean the actual symbol $\wedge$, or do you mean exponentiation of sets, like $X^Y$ (which is coded with the caret `^`)?

Comment: (The linked question has $X^Y$, and the answer there has $\land$)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Actually, the answer to that question contains both. I assumed he meant $\wedge$ because I edited posts with no typesetting all day and he seemed not too familiar with MathJax to me. I'm sorry if I was mistaken :}

Comment: @Arturo Magidin I was trying to solve 3.4.6 in Tao's analysis and I was reading through the first answer in the fourth line and this symbol just popped up. I have seen it in other proofs on the subject despite the fact it has no explanation in Tao's book.

Comment: Apologies I have just worked out the confusion, I misread the original confusion, I was asking about the wedge symbol $\wedge$, not ^ I just thought they were the same.

Comment: @KristianStokkereit Well, the exponentiation $Y^X$ is explained in the same page (Axiom 3.10). What we haven't still grasped is whether you meant $\wedge$ as in $x=0\wedge y=1$, or the exponentiation $Y^X$.

Comment: Oh, okay. I guess it's settled then :}

Comment: It is worth reminding also that symbols sometimes get overused.  Apart from the [logical conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) the wedge symbol $\wedge$ also appears in other contexts as the [meet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet) operator in a lattice, the [exterior (wedge) product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) of vectors, and others...

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree, I would avoid using "$\wedge$" for logical conjunction, *especially* when discussing Analysis and Geometry.

Comment: @JMoravitz Couldn't have put it better, I keep seeing it in set texts with no justification either in Tao's analysis or on the internet. I have just realised that if I had searched for wedge meaning rather than ^ it would have been much easier to find the answer, but  hindsight is a wonderful thing.  I wrote this rather hastily and little irritated, lesson learned.

Comment: For future reference, and to avoid this whole confusion: When asking about a symbol don’t just provide a link to a large body of text. Specify the exact location of the symbol, and/or include the exact line of text in question.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's a bit of confusion on this (maybe a bit overused) symbol, I think it's worth mentioning at least some of the most common uses for $\wedge$ (which does, after all, descend from the caret `^`, if I'm not mistaken).

In set theory and propositional logic, $\wedge$ is usually used for the logical conjunction AND. This is why this symbol is encoded both by `\wedge` and `\land` in LaTeX (hence, in MathJax). It's "opposite" is the "vel" operator $\vee$, which is the logical disjunction OR.

In lattice theory, $\vee$ and $\wedge$ are respectively the *join* and *meet* operators, which are used to denote supremum and infimum of a subset of a partially ordered set.

Another use of $\wedge$ is the *exterior (or wedge) product* in geometry, which is an antisymmetric binary operation. You can find it for example in differential forms (sections of the exterior power of the cotangent bundle, or locally/heuristically speaking, "wedge products of differentials").

Finally, in measure theory and analysis, $f\wedge g$ is often used to denote a function defined by $f\wedge g(x)=\inf \{f(x),g(x)\}$, as opposed to $f\vee g(x)=\sup\{f(x),g(x)\}$.

---

The caret `^` usually defines some kind of exponentiation, but it's not used as "proper" notation, but rather as encoding only (for example, $x^{a+b}$ is encoded as `$x^{a+b}$`).

Answer (score 0):

$X^Y$ where $X,Y$ are sets means the set of functions from $Y$ to $X$.

When $Y$ is finite, it resembles Cartesian product. For example, $\mathbb{R}^n$ means the set of $n$-tuples of reals (implying ordering).

What's an $n$-tuple? Each instance of $\mathbb{R}^n$ means: when you query an index number $i$ where $1\leq i\leq n$, you get a real number in return. And that is the same as a function mapping from indices $\{1, 2, 3,...,n\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Collectively, the set $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equivalent as the set of functions mapping from $\{1, 2, 3,...,n\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It works in similar ways for infinite sets.

Comment: I don't think that he was referring to exponentiation

Comment: @OttavioBartenor: if he wasn't, he wouldn't refer to "power set".

Comment: @Argyll What? The linked question is about power sets, but that doesn't mean that $\wedge$ suddenly loses its usual meaning.

Comment: @user3482749 without more context, I can not see reason to believe that the symbol in question is necessarily a wedge as opposed to a caret.  I could imagine someone writing `X^Y` and someone else coming behind to ask about the meaning of `^` just as I could see someone writing $P\wedge Q$ and someone coming behind and asking about $\wedge$.  I agree with argyll that it seems more likely that the question of the symbol may have been in reference to `^` and not in reference to $\wedge$ given the context of the question... however... without full details from the OP it is unclear.

Comment: See the comments from OP on this question for more clarity on this matter

Comment: I meant $\wedge$ and thought they were the same, I am really sorry if this has caused some confusion.

Comment: @user3482749: It does not. I didn't think OP refers to the symbol but thought they referred to ^ in typesetting when it means power/exponentiation. I'll leave it to OP to clarify in their question.