# Unsure of logic in my proof that Power Set Axiom for functions implies existence of Set of Subsets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Question**

I am **unsure of the validity or completeness of the logic** in my solution proof to Exercise 3.4.6 of Tao's Analysis I 4th Ed. I am self-teaching and the skills involved in logic, proof, quantifiers, etc are new to me.

> Prove Lemma 3.4.10. (Hint: start with the set $\{0, 1\}^X$ and apply
> the replacement axiom, replacing each function $f$ with the object
> $f^{-1}(\{1\})$.)

Note, I can't use "Cartesian products" as the exercise is before that point in the book.

---

**Relevant Axioms and Lemmas**

**Lemma 3.4.10**

Let $X$ be a set. Then $\{Y :Y \text{ is a subset of } X\}$ is a set.

**Axiom of Replacement 3.7**

Let $A$ be a set. For any object $x \in A$, and any object $y$, suppose we have a statement $P(x, y)$ pertaining to $x$ and $y$, such that for each $x \in A$ there is at most one $y$ for which $P(x, y)$ is true. Then there exists a set

$$\{y : P(x, y) \text{ is true for some } x \in A\}$$

such that for any object $z$,

$$ z \in \{y : P(x, y) \text{ is true for some } x \in A\} \iff P(x,z) \text{ is true for some } x \in A$$

**Power Set Axiom 3.11**

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Then there exists a set, denoted $Y^X$, which consists of all the functions from $X$ to $Y$, thus

$$f  \in Y^X \iff (f : X \to Y )$$

Note that this is about the existence of a set of functions - not the existence of a set of subsets, commonly referred to as the power set.

---

**My Solution**

Let's start arbitrary set $X$ and a specific set $Y=\{0,1\}$.

**Step 1:**

The Power Set Axiom 3.7 tells us that there **exists** a set $\{0,1\}^X$, which consists of all the functions $f$ from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$.

$$\{0,1\}^X = \{f: X \to \{0,1\}\}$$

**Step 2:**

Now let's apply the Axiom of Replacement 3.7 to this set. Consider a statement $P$ as follows:

$$P(f, A) : A = f^{-1}(\{1\})$$

The statement $P$ is true if the set $A$ is the inverse image of $\{1\}$ with respect to the function $f$.

There is at most one (actually, exactly one) $A$ satisfying the statement $P$ for each $f$, thus we can use the replacement axiom.

The reason there is exactly one $A$ for each $f$ is by definition of inverse images (**is this correct #1?**).

Thus, by the Axiom of Replacement, there **exists** a set

$$B=\{A: A=f^{-1}(\{1\})\}$$

This set $B$ consists of the inverse images of $\{1\}$ for every $f \in \{0,1\}^X$.

**Step 3:**

We now need to show that

- each $A=f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is a subset of $X$
- the set $B$ consists of all subsets of $X$

If $x \in A = f^{-1}(\{1\})$ then by definition of inverse images, $f(x) \in \{1\}$. Since $\{1\}$ is in $Y$, and the function is $f$, by definition of a function (domain, co-domain, mapping) we conclude $x \in X$. Thus $x \in f^{-1}(\{1\}) \implies x \in X$. That is $x \in A \implies A \subseteq X$. (**is this correct #2?**)

We'll show $B$ consists of all subsets of $X$. We start by noting that the power set $Y^X$ consists of **all** the functions $f:X \to Y$. We also note that each function $f$ has a unique inverse image of $\{1\}$. Thus the set established by the axiom of replacement, $B$ consists of **all** the inverse images of $\{1\}$. This $B$ consists of **all** the subsets of $X$. (**is this correct #3?**)

@drhab's [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538905/power-set-axiom-terence-tao-analysis-3-4-6) seems to follow this same logic (only, and every) but I can't understand that solution as it is too terse for me (beginner).

**Step 4:**

We have shown that if $X$ is a set, then there exists a set of subsets of $X$.

---

**Additional Question About The Proof's Logic**

Would this argument work if $Y=\{0,1,2\}$?

My intuition suggests the argument above will work for any $Y$ with cardinality more than one. Every element of $X$ has to map to something in $Y$. If $Y$ only has one element, then every element of $X$ must map to that single element of $Y$, preventing any partitioning of $X$ into subsets. For $Y$ with cardinality, say 5, then we still have every possible combination of subsets as inverse images of any single chosen element of $Y$.

Comment: Showing that $B$ contains all subsets of $X$ actually boils down to proving that for every subset $A\subseteq X$ we can find a function $f:X\to Y=\{0,1\}$ such that $A=f^{-1}(\{1\})$. The function prescribed by: $x\mapsto1$ if $x\in A$ and $x\mapsto 0$ otherwise does the job. Secondly: yes, it can be done using any $Y$ that has more than one element. Shortly: it looks okay to me.

Comment: @drhab - thank you for your reply, I really appreciate it. I am self-teaching and supportive and helpful replies like yours both help and build confidence.

Comment: As a more general question, is the following true? If I have a function defined with domain and codomain as $F:X \to Y$, and I know that $f(x) \in Y$, then can I conclude that $x$ must be in $X$ ? This has popped up in the above and other exercises.

Comment: If $X$ is the domain of a function $f$ then by definition *the existence* of $f(x)$ is already enough to conclude that $x\in X$.